# How high should I pull the bar when doing the upright row?

Tags: safety

I am actually trying to do the cuban press based on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLrTJRtudYQ&ab_channel=SpartanAesthetix), and one of the starting steps is to do an upright row to get the dumbbells into position. My question is, how much should I move my shoulder when I bring the dumbbells up? Alternatively, is it better to go till the limit of how much I can upright row the barbell ups or stop prematurely?

Answer (score 0):

Upright rows are used to work your side delta just like lateral raises. As such you want to bring your elbows up to the same height as your shoulders which equates to lifting the bar/dumbell to just under your chin.